# Access django server on VirtualBox/Vagrant machine from host browser?

Tags: python, django, vagrant

I have a Django web server on a VirtualBox/Vagrant machine running "bento/centos-6.7-i386".
I have followed this guide to create a Django project: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

I have a web server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ inside my guest machine. This is the first time I am running a Django web server. It is supposed to be a hello world app.

How can I access this web application from my host browser?
I tried adding this line - `config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "55.55.55.5"` in the vagrant file and then tried to run the `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80` command as per 1 of the solutions explained in previous discussions by others but I couldn't access the site from my host browser using 55.55.55.5:8000.

How can I access the web server from my browser?

Following given is my Vagrant File:

```
# -- mode: ruby -- 
# vi: set ft=ruby : 
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2" 
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config| 
config.vm.box = "bento/centos-6.7-i386" 
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8000 
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080 
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5000, host: 5000 
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.10.10.10" 
end
```

Comment: Try `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` and access port 8000 of your host machine.

Comment: if you did run `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80` make sure to add a line `config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8800` so you forward the port 80 from your VM (where you have the server running) to the host port 8800 so you can access http://localhost:8800/ from your host web browser (sometime you need to change localhost to 127.0.0.1 depending browser and configuration)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using below line in your `Vagrantfile` for port forwarding

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8000
```

It means you will be able to access your guest application which running at port `8000` in your host browser at port `8000`. so you will be able access by hitting `http://127.0.0.1:8000`  or `http://localhost:8000` in your host.

why you are forcing your app to run on `0.0.0.0` ? . 
it is not required , or if you want to access with guest IP address then there is no sense to use port forwarding.

if you changed this configuration in `Vagrantfile` after provision then don`t forget to reload

```
vagrant reload
```

Comment: Thanks worked for me as well. But had to add the IP to the allowed host list in admin.py

Answer (score 9):

You're forwarding port 8000 on the guest to 8000 on the host. Try:

```
python manage.py runserver 0:8000
```

Then in your browser visit: http://localhost:8000

That'll leave port 80 free if you end up wanting to run a web server for testing as well. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I got a problem with Django and port forwarding insider VB.

Django doesn't allow external hosts to access it.

So change the start command to
python3  ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

and everything worked